# "Timeout expired" exception happens before the defined timeout

Tags: sql-server, exception, ado.net

Using ADO.NET and SQL Server 2008.

The SqlCommand's `CommandTimeout` property was not changed, so it has the default value of 30.

The application runs some dozens command and logs the result (or exception) to an SQL table, so i know the start time of each execution. The start time of the next log record gives me an estimate of the duration.

I got two exception that don't make sense, because their duration is much smaller than the defined `CommandTimeout`.

This happend randomly. It's not reproducible.

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

My question is: can this exception be raised by other causes than and actual timeout?

Comment: There are two timeouts, one at the connection level and one at the command level. What is the connection timeout? Usually it's defined on the connection string.

Comment: @rsbarro: I'm aware of that. The connection TimeOut is 15 - which still doesn't explain this behavior, has the exceptin happened 2 to 5 seconds after the previous command.

Comment: Are you processing XML in your stored procedure query?

Comment: Could you check with SQL Server by executing your stored procedure and let us know how much time it takes? If it takes longer than usual, you should fine tune your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably related with some lock in participating tables.